Tamir.SharpSSH connection Timeout
We're facing a problem when trying to move files using Tamir.SharpSSH dll library from a server to another.
The server is a Windows server 2016 and the destination server is a RHEL 8.8 server with samba service started.
We call for the dll from an executable on a windows server 2016 with all the necessary component in the working folder (DiffieHelman.dll, Tamir.SharpSSH.dll and Org.Mentalis.Security.dll).
The conf file is for the executable file has this entry for the SFTP file transfer:
`<add key="date_time_format" value="dd-MM-yyyy" />
   <add key="group_name" value="REROUTING" />
   <add key="entity" value="Rerouting_ConnettoreBolli" />
   <add key="sftp_file_path" value="/path/Bolli" />
   <add key="sftp_host" value="10.213.70.110" />
   <add key="sftp_username" value="user" />
   <add key="sftp_password" value="password" />
   <add key="csv_separator" value=";" />
   <add key="source_class_name" value="ConnettoreBolli.SourceBolli" />`

It has always worked just fine but then we switched the destination server from a CentOS 7.9 to a RHEL 8.8 and now when we run the application we receive the following error.

Session.connect: System.IO.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.IO.getByte(Byte[] array, Int32 begin, Int32 length)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.read(Buffer buf)
at Tamir.SharpSsh.jsch.Session.connect(Int32 connectTimeout)

We can SFTP the destination folder both from client (mobaxterm) and from command line but not when we use the application.
Can you help me figure out the problem or guide me to the correct path
Thank you
We've tried to reconfigure the Samba server on the destination server and everything works fine till you try to use this protocol.
We're expecting the file moving to work as before

What exactly has this to do with Java?

sorry, my mistake, added when searching through the tag for the request
